# Sequelize raw query does not returns the exact result from the Postgres DB

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have a sequelize raw query to select some values from the database.But when running the query in postgres ie generated by sequelize gives 2 rows and in sequelize output ,it returns only 1 row and the value returned is mix of both rows.Following is my code.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
let sequelize;
sequelize = new Sequelize('db_oauth2','postgres', 'postgres',{ host: 'localhost',dialect: 'postgres'});
const invoices = await sequelize.query("SELECT invoice_amount,  bill_period_from,to_char(bill_period_from,'Month') as month, bill_period_to FROM invoices  WHERE invoices.user_id="+user_id+" and date_part('year', bill_period_from) = date_part('year', current_date) order by bill_period_from", { type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW});
console.log(invoices);
```

Form the console the output is

```
Executing (default): SELECT invoice_amount,  bill_period_from,to_char(bill_period_from,'Month') as month, bill_period_to FROM invoices  WHERE invoices.user_id=112 and date_part('year', bill_period_from) = date_part('year', current_date) order by bill_period_from

[ [ anonymous {
      invoice_amount: '120.000',
      bill_period_from: 2018-01-31T18:30:00.000Z,
      month: 'January  ',
      bill_period_to: 2018-02-27T18:30:00.000Z } ],
  Result {
    command: 'SELECT',
    rowCount: 1,
    oid: null,
    rows: [ [Object] ],
    fields: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    _parsers: 
     [ [Function],
       [Function: parseDate],
       [Function: noParse],
       [Function: parseDate] ],
    RowCtor: [Function: anonymous],
    rowAsArray: false,
    _getTypeParser: [Function: bound ] } ]
```

I executed the same query copied from the console in postgres client and got the result as follows

```
(invoice_amount;bill_period_from;month,bill_period_to)
300.000;"2018-01-01 00:00:00+05:30";"January  ";"2018-01-31 00:00:00+05:30"
120.000;"2018-02-01 00:00:00+05:30";"February ";"2018-02-28 00:00:00+05:30"
```

So in sequelize,it retrieves only one row ie the second row in postgres output and the value of the column month is of the first row in postgres output.How this happens and is sequelize is  not  a stable ORM.
Sequelize version 4.26 
Postgres 9.5

Answer (score 0):

By default sequelize.query(sql, options) has `options.type` equals `raw` and returns full response with the Result object.

By specifying `options.type` as `sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT` you can get data only response.

Please refer to official [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-method-query).